# Delete file from Azure Blog container

Tags: azure, flutter, dart

I want to delete exist in AzureBlobStorage. I have successfully saved images on this storage. I want to achieve it with some kind of API.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the existing rest API for blob storage?

The [**`Delete File`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delete-file2) operation immediately removes the file from the storage account.

**Method    Request URI**

> DELETE    https://myaccount.file.core.windows.net/myshare/mydirectorypath/myfile